# How to find the indexes of the first $n$ maximum values of a tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch, argmax

I know that `torch.argmax(x, dim = 0)` returns the index of the first maximum value in `x` along dimension `0`. But is there an efficient way to return the indexes of the first `n` maximum values? If there are duplicate values I also want the index of those among the `n` indexes.

As a concrete example, say `x=torch.tensor([2, 1, 4, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1])`. I would like a function

```
generalized_argmax(xI torch.tensor, n: int)
```

such that
`generalized_argmax(x, 4)`
returns `[0, 2, 4, 5]` in this example.

Comment: In case you (future-reader) are looking for a solution without duplicates look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63440455/how-can-i-select-top-n-elements-from-tensor-without-repeating-elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To acquire all you need to go over the whole tensor anyway, the most efficient should therefore be to use `argsort` manually limited to `n` entries.

```
>>> x=torch.tensor([2, 1, 4, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1])
>>> x.argsort(dim=0, descending=True)[:n]
[2, 4, 0, 5]
```

Sort it again to get `[0, 2, 4, 5]` if you need the ascending order of indices.